# How do I print to stdout in proper columns?

Tags: c

I have a program where I am printing to a file, and I would like to print my columns in steady columns.

You can see here by looking at the output of my file what I am trying to say

Output: http://nopaste.dk/p15072

Here is what I wrote:

```
int func1(int n) {
        if(n==0){return(6);}
    return ((int)log2(n));
}
char levelStrings[7] = {'L','M','H','E','F','C','X'};
fprintf(fp, "%s  %s  %d   %c    ",tString+11,log->file,log->line,levelStrings[func1(log->ssMask%64)]);
```

Thanks so much!

(sorry that i cannot provide the input data, as they are Hex info that I have made a parser for, and it is just too much code to paste. I hope you get the general idea of what I am trying to do.)

Comment: Add field widths to your format specifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in the following lines and it should work.

```
fprintf(fp,"%8s%8s%4d%2c",tString+11,log->file,log->line,levelStrings[func1(log->ssMask%64)]);
```